# слить три отсортированных файла

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

здравствуйте, есть задача слить 3 отсортированных файла в один... подскажите алгоритм действий, не могу въехать толком, особенно если у файлов совершенно разные размеры...

Comment: `sort -m <files>...`

Comment: я решил мозги прокачать, так что сам делаю

Comment: Если речь идет об алгоритме, то при чем здесь [C++] и [C]. Если же речь идеи об реализации, то может имеет смысл выбрать один язык?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для трёх последовательностей, работает простейший алгоритм:

- выводим минимум из текущих трёх значений и сдвигаем последовательность, содержащую минимум
- если любая из последовательностей закончилась, то используем алгоритм для двух последовательностей

```cpp
#include <algorithm> // merge

template <class It, class OutIt> // InputIterator, OutputIterator
OutIt merge3(It afirst, It aend, It bfirst, It bend, It cfirst, It cend,
             OutIt out)
{
  for ( ; ; ) {
    if (afirst == aend)
      return std::merge(bfirst, bend, cfirst, cend, out);
    else if (bfirst == bend)
      return std::merge(afirst, aend, cfirst, cend, out);
    else if (cfirst == cend)
      return std::merge(afirst, aend, bfirst, bend, out);

    auto a = *afirst, b = *bfirst, c = *cfirst;
    if (a < b) {
      if (a < c) {
        *out++ = a; // a < b && a < c i.e., a == min(a, b, c)
        ++afirst;
      } else {
        *out++ = c; // a < b && !(a < c) i.e.,  b > a >= c
        ++cfirst;
      }
    } else if (b < c) {
        *out++ = b; // !(a < b) && b < c i.e., a >= b && c > b
        ++bfirst;
    } else {
        *out++ = c; //  !(a < b) && !(b < c) i.e., a >= b >= c
        ++cfirst;
    }
  }
}
```

К примеру, чтобы объединить отсортированные последовательности чисел из файлов `a`, `b`, `c`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <iterator>  
#include <fstream>   // ifstream

int main()
{
  std::ifstream afile("a"), bfile("b"), cfile("c");
  typedef std::istream_iterator<int> It;
  merge3(It(afile), It(), It(bfile), It(), It(cfile), It(),
         std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Чтобы объединить отсортированные строки:

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include "merge.hpp"

int main()
{
  const char* a[] = {"aabbc", "bcdd", "acdfff"};
  merge3(a[0], a[0] + std::strlen(a[0]),
         a[1], a[1] + std::strlen(a[1]),
         a[2], a[2] + std::strlen(a[2]),
         std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Результат:

```cpp
a a a b b b c c c d d d f f f
```

Чтобы поместить результат в строку, вместо вывода на экран, [можно `std::back_inserter(s)` использовать (где `s` это `std::string`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) вместо `ostream_iterator<>()`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  string a[] = {"aabbc", "bcdd", "acdfff"};
  string s;
  merge3(begin(a[0]), end(a[0]),
         begin(a[1]), end(a[1]),
         begin(a[2]), end(a[2]),
         back_inserter(s));
  cout << s;
}
```

Результат:

```cpp
aaabbbcccdddfff
```

### mergek() — объединение `k` сортированных последовательностей

Чтобы поддерживать произвольное количество файлов `k`, можно использовать кучу (heap), чтобы для каждого элемента не приходилось бы каждый раз `~k` сравнений производить, чтобы новый минимум найти:

```cpp
template <class MinHeap, class OutIt>
OutIt mergek(MinHeap& heap, OutIt out)
{
  while(!heap.empty()) {
    auto range = heap.top(); // pop minimum in O(1)
    heap.pop();

    *out++ = *range.first++; // output the minimum, move input

    if (range.first != range.second) // push unless empty range
      heap.emplace(range); // find new minimum in O(log k)
  }
  return out;
}
```

До тех пор пока есть последовательности в куче (в виде пары итераторов, указывающих на первый и за последний элемент соответственно):

1. выбирается последовательность из кучи, соответствующая минимальному элементу
2. выводится в результат и соответствующая позиция в последовательности сдвигается
3. сдвинутая позиция добавляется назад в кучу, чтобы новый минимум найти.
4. повтор

Смысл использования heap в том, что используется порядка `O(log k)` сравнений вместо `O(k)`, если просто набор `k` последовательностей   хранить (`log10(1000000) == 6` так что `O(log k)` значительно лучше чем `O(k)` для достаточно большого `k`).

К примеру, чтобы объединить произвольное число файлов заданных в командной строке:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  using namespace std;

  // input files are streams (iterators) of ints here
  typedef istream_iterator<int> It;
  // the heap contains pairs of iterators over files: (current_position, eof)
  typedef pair<It, It> Range;
  auto greater_first = [](Range lhs, Range rhs) {
    return *lhs.first > *rhs.first; 
  };
  priority_queue<Range, vector<Range>, decltype(greater_first)>
    heap(greater_first);
  ifstream file[argc]; //NOTE: dummy file[0]
  while (--argc) {
    file[argc].open(argv[argc]); //NOTE: ignore errors
    heap.emplace(It(file[argc]), It());
  }
  mergek(heap, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

Пример запуска:

```cpp
$ ./merge-k a b c
```

Каждый входной файл, как и в случае `merge3()`, представлен как пара итераторов: `(current_position, eof)`. Эти пары заносятся в кучу (`priority_queue<>`), чтобы можно было бы быстро минимум находить среди текущих позиций во всех файлах. Сравнение происходит с помощью `greater_first()` функции (используется `>` операция, так как по умолчанию `priority_queue<>` возвращает наибольший элемент, а мы хотим минимум найти).

Можно перенести создание кучи внутрь `mergek()` (код практически идентичен тому, что выше в `main()` написано, но работает не только с файлами):

```cpp
#include <queue>
#include <utility>   // pair
#include <vector>

template <class RandomIt, class OutIt>
OutIt mergek(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, OutIt out)
{
  typedef decltype(begin(*first)) It;
  typedef std::pair<It, It> Range;
  auto greater_first_it = [](Range a, Range b) {
    return *b.first < *a.first;
  };
  std::priority_queue<Range, std::vector<Range>, decltype(greater_first_it) >
    heap(greater_first_it);
  for ( ; first != last; ++first)
    heap.emplace(std::begin(*first), std::end(*first));
  return mergek(heap, out);
}
```

Чтобы объединить отсортированные строки:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  string a[] = {"aabbc", "bcdd", "acdfff"};
  mergek(begin(a), end(a), ostream_iterator<char>(cout, " "));
}
```

Результат:

```cpp
a a a b b b c c c d d d f f f
```

Comment: хм, а std::merge в данном случае в память не загоняет ничего?

Comment: @xperious: нет. Как [merge()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) так и merge3 не используют дополнительную память (кроме 2-3 значений, которые в данный момент сравниваются). Если вы скормите сетевые потоки, то merge3() может вообще никогда не закончится (пока ввод не прекратится). Почитайте о понятиях [InputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator), [OutputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator).

Comment: и про бинарную кучу можно чуток поподробнее? в каком месте ее использовать

Comment: @xperious если у вас не три файла, а тысяча файлов, то чтобы каждый раз 1000 элементов не сравнивать, чтобы новый минимум найти после сдвига последовательности, то можно использовать кучу (специальная структура данных, позволяющая эффективно минимальный/максимальный элемент выдергивать и дёшево новые элементы добавлять). См. [`std::pop_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap) и [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)

Comment: хм, буду разбираться

Comment: @xperious: я добавил mergek() вариант

Comment: хм, так логарифм же двоичный, а не десятичный... log(1000000) примерно равен 20

реализация убойная конечно, сам бы я точно не допер бы

Comment: @xperious: вам [следует с big O нотацией познакомиться](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%ABO%C2%BB_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%C2%ABo%C2%BB_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5)¶ 1- я использовал явное обозначение log10 (логарифм c основанием 10)¶ 2- обычно `log()` использует `e` (`2.718`...), а не `2` основание¶ 3- В записи `O(log k)` не имеет значения какой log, к примеру: `log10(x) = log(x) / log(10)`, поэтому `O(log10 k) === O(log k / log 10) == O(log k)` (константы в big O нотации не имеют значения).

Answer (score 5):

Ну точно так, как я вам [уже отвечал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/620905/195342) на предыдущий вопрос:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void makeFile(const char * name)
{
    ofstream out(name);
    int curval = rand()%100;
    for(int j = 0; j < 10000+rand()%100; ++j)
    {
        out << curval << "\n";
        curval += rand()%100;
    }
}

struct Get
{
    int val;
    ifstream* f;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    makeFile("data1");  // Создали три отсортированных файла
    makeFile("data2");
    makeFile("data3");

    vector<Get> ps;        // Вектор структуры с последним считанным значением и указателем, откуда читаем
    ifstream in1("data1");
    ifstream in2("data2");
    ifstream in3("data3");

    int x;
    in1 >> x;                // Читаем из первого файла
    ps.push_back({x,&in1});  // и вносим в вектор файлов
    in2 >> x;                // Читаем из второго файла
    ps.push_back({x,&in2});  // и вносим в вектор файлов
    in3 >> x;                // Читаем из третьего файла
    ps.push_back({x,&in3});  // и вносим в вектор файлов

    ofstream out("sort");    // Выходной файл
    for(;ps.size();)         // Пока есть какие-то данные (что читать)
    {                        // Находим минимальный элемент из трех фвйлов
        auto g = min_element(ps.begin(), ps.end(),
                             [](const Get&g1, const Get&g2) { return g1.val < g2.val; });
        out << g->val << "\n";    // Выводим его в новый файл
        if (!((*g->f) >> g->val)) // Читаем из файла, откуда был взят элемент, новый элемент
        {                         // Если не удалось (конец файла)
            ps.erase(g);          // Выбрасываем этот файл из рассмотрения
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: да я никак не пойму что значит in1 >> x, как и в вашем предыдущем примере) как вы без цикла то читаете весь файл?

Comment: Дописал комментарии. `in1 >> x` - чтение целого числа из файлового потока (`ifstream`) `in1` в переменную `x`.

Comment: все-таки это гениально... вы ведь вообще в память не пишете файлы, вот такой подход надо запомнить

Comment: кстати работает не совсем правильно)

Comment: В чем именно? Я проверял, как вы понимаете... Три сгенерированных файла собрал, отсортировал и сравнил с выводом программы - совпало. Где вы нашли ошибку?

Comment: не, у меня косяк

Comment: все-таки поражаюсь лаконичности кода

Answer (score 4):

Открыть все три и прочитать первые токены. Найдя среди них минимальный, сбросить его в выход и подчитать из этого файла следующий. Повторять, пока все файлы не закончатся.

Comment: забавно, но ваш коммент мне помог)

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Автор просит алгоритм, а не готовую программу. Наверное, потому, что хочет научиться. а не сдать и забыть. А вот если для Вас алгоритм - это программа на С, то мне Вас немножко жаль...

Comment: да просто решил разобраться)

Comment: Видите ли, Akina, я разделяю этот взгляд http://lpcs.math.msu.su/~uspensky/bib/Uspensky_1958_UMN_Kolmogorov_Opredelenie_algoritma.pdf на понимание алгоритма. То, что Вы написали предполагает наличие человеческого интеллекта и не удовлетворяет формальным требованием. Кстати, автор вопроса справедливо назвал Вашу реплику комментарием, а не ответом. С примерами, как нужно писать ответы Вы можете ознакомиться ниже Вашего комментария. ;)

Comment: _Кстати, автор вопроса справедливо назвал Вашу реплику комментарием, а не ответом._ Не спорю. Но ведь помогло?

Comment: @Akina: Stack Overflow не является форумом или сайтом взаимопомощи в традиционном его понимании: если человек пришёл из гугла с вопросом как "слить три отсортированных файла" в С++, то желателен ответ, который содержит код. Хотя, учитывая простоту алгоритма и разнообразие форм как входные данные задаются и как вывод принимается, то простое словесное описание также является приемлемым ответом (поэтому я вам плюс поставил), но само по себе отсутствие кода не делает ответ лучше. Язык имеет значение, так как на Питоне, я бы просто [`heapq.merge(*files)` вызвал бы](https://goo.gl/MBRVWr).