# Алгоритмы слияния двух неупорядоченных массивов

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

Недавно начал знакомство с сортировкой слиянием и понял, что я понятия не имею как происходит слияние неупорядоченных массивов, и какие алгоритмы существуют для этой цели. Как реализовать сортировку слиянием рекурсивно я прекрасно понимаю, а вот именно подробное описание алгоритма(ов) слияния подмассивов, я так и не нашел.

Можете подробно рассказать про алгоритм(мы) слияния массивов, либо дать короткое четкое и понятное объяснение на эту тему, или дать ссылку на источники, где это все подробно объясняется?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "слиянием неупорядоченных массивов"? Если они неупорядочены - просто добавьте один в конец второго, и дело с концом :) Или вы хотите чего-то иного?

Comment: Ну это было бы очень просто) Да и правда забыл упомянуть, что после слияния двух массивов, в итоге должен получиться упорядоченный массив.

Comment: Тогда просто слияния недостаточно, это всего лишь часть [сортировки слиянием](https://habr.com/post/281675/)

Comment: В сортировке слиянием всегда происходит слияние именно *упорядоченных* массивов. Откуда взялись "неупорядоченные"?

Comment: [слить три отсортированных файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621251/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, в алгоритме *сортировки слиянием* действительно в качестве под-алгоритма используется алгоритм слияния двух последовательностей (массивов, списков и т.п.). Однако слияние выполняется именно для *упорядоченных* последовательностей. В этом вся суть алгоритма *сортировки слиянием*. Поэтому не ясно, почему в своем вопросе вы говорите о "слиянии *неупорядоченных* массивов". Откуда взялись неупорядоченные массивы? И какое это имеет отношение к сортировке слиянием?

Во-вторых, алгоритм слияния двух *упорядоченных* последовательностей тривиален: просто на каждом шаге алгоритма выбираем *минимальный* из начальных элементов наших входных последовательностей и перемещаем его на выход. Повторяем, пока не исчерпаем входные последовательности. Все.

В-третьих, если речь идет именно о *массивах*, то вышеупомянутый тривиальный алгоритм слияния легко применим только в том случае, если мы имеем возможность на основе двух входных массивов формировать третий (отдельный) слитый массив. Так обычно и реализуется сортировка массивов слиянием - она требует дополнительной памяти для формирования слитых результатов. Однако существуют [эффективные алгоритмы](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397598001625), которые умеют сливать соседствующие в памяти массивы прямо *на месте* ("in-place"), без привлечения третьего массива. Эти алгоритмы, однако, далеко не тривиальны и, как правило, не используются в практических реализациях сортировки слиянием.