# Слияние n последовательностей

Tags: алгоритм

Дано `n` упорядоченных по возрастанию (все числа натуральные, разные) последовательностей длины `k` каждая. Необходимо эффективно слить их в одну упорядоченную по возврастанию последовательность с исключением повторяющих элементов.

Comment: заводите массив нужной длины. А дальше делаете указатели на первые элементы каждого входного массива. Ищите там минимальный. Этот минимальный переписываете в результирующий массив и сдвигаете указатель в исходном. И ещё концовки нужно уметь обработать.

Comment: Гляньте [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/620839/%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB/620905#620905) или [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/621251/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0/621327#621327) - очень похожая задача.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [слить три отсортированных файла](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621251/23044) (ответы содержат алгоритмы, которые работают и при `n > 3`).

Answer (score 1):

Давайте начнём реализацию данного алгоритма с лобового решения, представляющего собой сортировку всей последовательности. Затем попробуем улучшить его и поглядим, что у нас получится.

Пусть мы имеем векторы набор последовательностей, как и в условии: `k` последовательностей длины `n`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запишем их в один вектор, друг за другом. Теперь, используя стандартную сортировку [qSort](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), получим отсортированный массив за `O(n log(n))`. Данная оценка имеет место быть, но неудовлетворительна. Попробуем улучшить наш алгоритм.

Введём особый контейнер, который называется [кучей (heap)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)). Данный контейнер хорош тем, что мы всегда можем извлечь из него максимум или минимум (`O(1)`), в зависимости от того, на что он нацелен. Одно временно хранить и то, и другое в стандартной реализации нельзя. Для этого нужны модификации. Недостаток кучи заключается в том, что добавление элемента осуществляется за `O(log(n))`.

Кроме того, рассмотрим некоторый профиль. Профилём назовём следующую конструкцию. Пусть `p` элементов в вектор уже добавлены. Тогда из каждой последовательности добавлено разное кол-во элементов. В таком случае, следующий за последним добавленным элементом -- есть элемент профиля. Совокупность всех таких элементов -- есть профиль. Приведём пример для n = 9, k = 7:

[image: Профиль]

На рисунке выше профилем будут выделенные элементы:

[image: Элементы профиля]

В результирующий массив окажутся добавлеными элементы:

[image: Результирующий массив]

Замечу, что в данном массиве элементы добавлены друг за другом построчно. Вообще говоря, это не всегда будет так. В данном случае -- это лишь совпадение.

Теперь, коль скоро мы объяснили, что есть профиль, сформируем из него кучу. Каждый раз, будем вытаскивать из кучи один минимальный элемент и добавлять его к результирующему массиву. Т.е.

[image: Получение минимального элемента]

после чего `answ` добавляем в результирующий массив.

Итак, имеем следующий алгоритм:

1. Инициализируем профиль элементами a_{i1} и стороим из них кучу.
2. Извлекаем минимальный элемент (`answ`) из кучи и номер последовательности (`index`) и последнего элемента в последовательности (`last`).
3. Добавляем извлечённый элемент к ответу и модифицируем кучу (профиль), добавляя в неё элемент `a_{index last}`. Переходим к `шагу 1`. Если такого элемента нет, то переходим к `шагу 3`.
4. Последовательно извлечём все элементы из кучи и добавим извлечённый элементы к ответу.

Оценим сложность алгоритма. Понятно, что мы перебираем все элементы и на каждой итерации производим извлечение элемента из кучи за `O(1)` и добавление нового элемента в кучу за `O(log(k))`, где `k` -- число последовательностей (размер профиля). В таком случае, сложность оказывается `O(n log(k))`. Если число последовательностей небольшое, а общее количество элементов велико (`n >> k`), то получим практически линейную сложность алгоритма.

Замечу, что, если про исходные данные будет известна дополнительная информация, то мы можем предложить более эффективный алгоритм.

Answer (score -1):

В случае если мы говорим о большом значении k ~ 10^8 (к сожалению вы не указали максимальное значение), то определяем последние значения в каждом массиве и выбираем из них максимальное (допустим это будет j)
Заводим массив с указателями на каком номере элемента мы остановились для каждого из n массивов, допустим массив t
Теперь проходим по массиву от q = 1 до q <= j и сравниваем q с элементом каждого массива, номер которого у нас хранится в t. Во всех массивах, где нашли совпадение, увеличиваем значение t[n] на единицу (говорим, что у n-го массива мы нашли элемент со значением q и теперь при следующей итерации надо будет проверять следующий элемент массива), ну и записываем это q в результирующий массив естественно.